# How to stop events which are getting logged into Windows Event Viewer Application Section?

Tags: mysql, events, connection

Title: Aborted connection to db 
There are thousands are events getting logged into Windows Event Viewer Application Section.
How to stop them or resolve them
MySQL Version : 5.7

See the below attached screen shot there are 75,000 + Events logged.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given in below link try increasing following things

```
[mysqld] 
max_allowed_packet=256M 
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024 * 1024 * 256;
```

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets